# Express server takes 500ms to return a 304 response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a very simple express server. It has `compression` and uses `static-serve` to serve files. I have `cacheControl` set to false, so it only uses the ETag.

The server will return a 304 for the files (which is desired), but it takes about 500ms to do so. That's the same amount of time it takes to actually send the file.

Is there some configuration I can do (outside of things like Varnish and nginx) to speed it up?

The server only has about 6 different files to serve up, all static.

Express server code:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9095;

const app = express();

app.use(compression({ threshold: 0 }));

app.use(/regex pattern here/, serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/client/assets'), { cacheControl: false }));

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  console.log(error || `Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the trick is to run the express server with `NODE_ENV=production`.

Apparently, this tells Express to do a number of optimizations, one of which seems to do exactly what I wanted. Went from about 500ms to about 40ms to return a 304, which is much better.

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#in-environment

Answer (score 1):

You should use nginx or something similar to serve static content because node serve-static module need to calculate hash from file content. So this is even slower than just serving file especially on local machine.
Here is deep dive into serve-static mechanics https://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/

Comment: why does it *need* to calculate the hash?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case though, I'm looking for something without using Varnish or nginx. It might be on me to just write some code to cache everything in memory since there are so few files being served up.